# Hierarchical ownership causing slow requests

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

I have some Wizards who belong to various Sects of magic. Being a member of a sect grants you special powers that you can use to smite your foes. Some of these sects have subsects which grants you additional powers.

```
@Entity
public class Sect {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private Sect parent;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Spell> spells;
}

@Entity
public class Wizard {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany 
    private Set<Sect> sects;
}
```

Now, I have a Wizard who is a member of the Order of the Oak. Order of the Oak is a subsect of Order of the Forest, which in turn is a subsect of Order of the Earth. (So `wizard.sects.contains(oak) == true`, and `oak.parent.parent.equals(earth) == true`). The spell "Earth Bolt" is granted by Order of the Earth. My Wizard isn't explicitly a member of the Order of the Earth, or even Order of the Forest. He was recruited by a member of the Order of the Oak. However, he is implicitly a member, and has access to all those spells. Right now, I am basically doing this:

```
boolean canCast(Wizard wizard, Spell spell) {
    Queue<Sect> toProcess = new ...
    toProcess.addAll(wizard.getSects());
    Set<Sect> processed = new ...
    while(!toProcess.isEmpty()) {
        Sect sect = toProcess.poll();
        if(!processed.add(sect)) continue; // already did this from a sister sect
        toProcess.add(sect.getParent());
        if(sect.getSpells().contains(spell))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But it seems so silly to pull all this information back when I really don't need to.

I know I have a few options, like keeping a table of your parent orders, so when you get added to the Order of the Oak, it adds you to Order of the Forest and Order of the Earth, but that seems wonky. It would be tough to manage things if you got removed from Order of the Oak and it deletes Forest and Earth... what if you were also part of Order of the Maple? You would still be in Forest and Earth. And that's just one case - I'm sure there's many cases where that would explode in my face.

Another option would be to keep track of the spells from Earth and Forest and put them in Oak and Maple. But what if a spell is explicitly offered by Oak that is also found in Earth? If I remove it from the Earth teaching, it shouldn't be removed from Oak. So I would really a reference to the Sect on the Spell class, and then add them all to the Sect and subsects. But that also seems like a lot of maintenance and error prone.

Another option would be to keep a cache of the entire spell-offering structure, and whenever something changes in an offering, just empty the table and reconstruct it. This would be an expensive operation when I'm editing the spell offerings, but that is a fairly rare occurrence.

Ideally, I have a single HQL (I suppose I could do NamedNative... but would like to avoid if I can) query that runs and fetches the information I need. But I don't know how to construct such a query, and if I did, how to make it not completely suck.

Are there any options I'm not thinking of? Any tools or tricks? I know hibernate has a lot of tricks!

Answer (score 1):

When writing Sect, add a method

```
isSubsectOf(Sect s)
```

which returns true if this Sect is a subsect of some other sect. It's recursive so it returns the aprent sec, the grandparent sect etc. Now you can check whether a Wizard is a member of a sect by

- testing if he is directly a member of that Sect
- testing if the sect he is a member of is a subsect of it

For completeness you probably also want to write something that lists for a given sect all the parent etc. sects of it.

To check for an ability, write a method on Sect 'canCast(Spell sp)' which checks not only if it is in the list of spells for that Sect, but also for all the parent Sects. A Wizard can cast a spell if canCast(Spell sp) returns true for the Sect he is a specific member of.

This is straightforward Java inheritance and doesn't require anything complicated

Comment: That's not much different than what I'm doing now. The problem is that not all the data is in memory: it's in the database. I want to reduce the scope of my transactions. Your `isSubsectOf` method will have to go fetch that parent from the database, which is what I'd like to avoid. I'd like the database to do the heavy lifting and reduce what has to come across the wire.

Comment: In fact, your "list all parents for a given sect" is exactly what I want - but I want to do it in the database in one trip.

Comment: Sometimes there is stuff the database is good at, and sometimes there is stuff the programming language is good at. This is something Java is good at. Since Java is good at it, use Java.

Comment: If the current solution was working, I would do it. Java can only be good at this if it can get all its data in a timely manner. In a recent enhancement, we added a search routine. The search took 44 seconds, and 43 of those seconds were just determining what spells could be cast. We ended up doing the cache-reconstruct solution and it cut it down to 2 seconds, but I'd like a better, more best-practicey solution going forward.